# Force all links in admin area to use www

Tags: magento-1.9, cors

Is there a way to force all links in the Magento admin area to use www?

We have a site that's been around for a long time and all the frontend URLs are indexed with 'www' at the start.

There were some issues with the htaccess rules which I've now changed to force all paths to have 'www' in and use https.

Now when we use the admin area we cant search any of the grids, we just get an ajax searching wheel and it gets stuck showing just an empty page (with header and footer, the grid just disappears)

If I check in the console it flags a CORS error. I think this is because all the links point to the non www domain instead of the 'www' version.

I tried adding this to the htaccess to allow cross-origin requests but it didn't seem to work.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

So, can anyone tell me which file or DB entry to change to force all the links to use the www version?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System->Configuraiton**  in the left tab select **Web** in the unsecured tab add the domain name with **www**

[image]

**OR**

- Go to **System -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Admin -> Admin Base URL**
- Select Use Custom Admin URL as 'Yes'
- Add full URL to your admin area with www in Custom Admin URL field.

[image]

Comment: Ive already tried that but all the links in admin still dont have the 'www' in. Ive set it with 'www' in default values and website and store view.

Comment: just updated the answer, did you check that? Even I had the same problem, this solved issue.

Comment: Sorry, Ive misread your answer, Thanks let me check it works

Comment: Ive added that and its half worked, it seems to have broken the links in the admin area and removed the double slash and the colon from the URL and replaced with a . so my links are now https.domain.com/folder/. I put the full url in the custom url field.

Comment: Which field you filled Custom Admin URL?

Comment: Just tried that but still broken. I cant login to the admin area since I first changed it so have been editing this through the database. I just tried putting a random string in the custom url to check it was doing something but it isnt visible anywhere. e.g. I put www.domain.com/testpath/ as the custom domain but on my login screen if I view source all the links are still [link]https.domain.com/[/link] so it appears this custom url isnt coming through properly

Comment: In the database I tried to put use custom url to 0 and deleted the custom url. Ive cleared cache but cant get the site back how it was now

Comment: clear the cache and browse in a different browser, check with store views as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93097/discussion-between-user3914769-and-rinto-george).